# Templating library for node.js with php-like syntax

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, template-engine

Is there a library for node.js to "parse" a content of a file with specific syntax?
In example, I have a file which I want to serve on my node.js server:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
    <?node echo Date.getTime(); ?> <!-- or something like this, I hope you have got the idea -->
</body>
</html>
```

Then it returns a HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
    08.08.2013 <!-- or something like this, I hope you have got the idea -->
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know how to describe it more precisly, something like PHP for Apache server, but for node.js server.

Comment: Just to add to the list: https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/ You've got lots of choices...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about a template engine. There are many possibilites, one of the most popular is *jade*:

http://jade-lang.com/

It is especially good when integrated with [Express frawework](http://expressjs.com/). You can find a big list of template engines here:

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-templating

Comment: and there is something that is more like a scripting language (like PHP, which I mentioned before)?

Comment: @AreWojciechowski Have a look at the list and pick one you like. [Kiwi](https://github.com/coolony/kiwi) might be what you are looking for. I don't know how mature it is though. Node.JS is not PHP so you will be forced to do some things differently.

Comment: @AreWojciechowski Kiwi or Jade are just templating engines supporting a subset of JS. But there is a full PHP-like JavaScript implementation called CGI-Node which I added [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40119038/912946).

Answer (score 4):

EJS templates look and feel like PHP and ASP but are pure JS: https://ejs.co/

Their example:

```
<ul>
<% for(var i=0; i<supplies.length; i++) {%>
   <li><%= supplies[i] %></li>
<% } %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Here is a tutorial on how to [use EJS with Node.js](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application).

Answer (score 4):

Just use [**CGI-Node**](http://www.cgi-node.org/). It allows you to run Node.js on any web hosting just like PHP:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <? var helloWorld = 'Hello World!'; ?>
        <?= helloWorld ?>
    <br>
    <b>I can count to 10: </b>
    <? for (var index = 0; index <= 10; index++) { ?>
        <?= index ?>
    <? } ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Underscore templates](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#template). It lets you write templates like this:

```
<ul>
<% _.each(people, function(name) { %>
  <li><%= name %></li>
<% }); %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

I might be a little late to the party, but I worked on something like this yesterday and it works surprisingly similar to php. E.g. you can do stuff like

```
<?j
include_once("header.jhtml");

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { ?>
<span id="<?j print(i) ?>">

<?j}
print($.req.url);
include("footer.jhtml");
?>
```

which will include the header file (if it was not included before) just like in php and then print 10 spans with id's from 0 to 9, then print the request url ($ is the context variable which includes the request data), then include the footer file. So it's basically php with js syntax. I will make it available on npm probably this weekend. It's very much in it's early stage though, as I said, I worked 1 day on it.